# Assigning value to group based on subgroup

Tags: r

In R, I have a df that looks somewhat like this:

```r
structure(
list(
`Family ID` = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2","3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4"),
`Subject ID` = c("1","2", "4", "1", "2", "4", "1", "2", "4", "5", "1", "2", "4", "5"),
X = c("1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1","2", "2", "2"), 
Y = c("1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1","2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2")
), row.names = 2:15, class = "data.frame"
)

#>    Family ID Subject ID X Y
#> 2          1          1 1 1
#> 3          1          2 2 2
#> 4          1          4 1 2
#> 5          2          1 1 1
#> 6          2          2 2 2
#> 7          2          4 2 2
#> 8          3          1 2 1
#> 9          3          2 1 1
#> 10         3          4 2 2
#> 11         3          5 1 2
#> 12         4          1 1 2
#> 13         4          2 2 1
#> 14         4          4 2 2
#> 15         4          5 2 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

My goal is to  make a new column that contains a value of 1 for all people with the same family ID, if and only if a subject ID of 4 or 5 contains a value of 1 in column x or column y. Thus, the result in this example would look like this:

```r
#>    Family ID Subject ID X Y Z
#> 2          1          1 1 1 1
#> 3          1          2 2 2 1
#> 4          1          4 1 2 1
#> 5          2          1 1 1 0
#> 6          2          2 2 2 0
#> 7          2          4 2 2 0
#> 8          3          1 2 1 1
#> 9          3          2 1 1 1
#> 10         3          4 2 2 1
#> 11         3          5 1 2 1
#> 12         4          1 1 2 0
#> 13         4          2 2 1 0
#> 14         4          4 2 2 0
#> 15         4          5 2 2 0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any help here is appreciated. Apologies in advance as I am new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'FamilyID', subset the 'X', 'Y' column where the SubjectID is 4 or 5, check if `any` of the values are equal to 1 and the compound logical expression is joined with OR (`|`) operator

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(FamilyID) %>% 
   mutate(Z = +(any(X[SubjectID %in% 4:5] == 1)|
              any(Y[SubjectID %in% 4:5] == 1))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 13 x 5
#   FamilyID SubjectID     X     Y     Z
#      <int>     <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1        1         1     1     1     1
# 2        1         2     2     2     1
# 3        1         4     1     2     1
# 4        2         1     1     1     0
# 5        2         2     2     2     0
# 6        3         1     2     1     1
# 7        3         2     1     1     1
# 8        3         4     2     2     1
# 9        3         5     1     2     1
#10        4         1     2     2     0
#11        4         2     2     2     0
#12        4         4     2     2     0
#13        4         5     2     2     0
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$Z <- with(df1, +(FamilyID %in% FamilyID[SubjectID %in% 
       4:5][rowSums(cbind(X, Y)[SubjectID %in% 4:5,] == 1) > 0]))
df1$Z
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(FamilyID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), SubjectID = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), X = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Y = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: akrun. Thank you!!

Comment: Dear Arun I've been thinking about a row-wise solution with `pmap` for this following our discussions recently, and I came up with this.

Answer (score 1):

**Special thanks** to dear @akrun for his helpful suggestions:

You can also use the following solution. I used data provided by dear @akrun.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(Z = pmap_dbl(list(SubjectID, X, Y), ~ if_else(..1 %in% c(4, 5) & any(c(..2, ..3) == 1), 1, 0))) %>%
  group_by(FamilyID) %>%
  mutate(Z = if_else(any(Z == 1), 1, 0))

# A tibble: 13 x 5
# Groups:   FamilyID [4]
   FamilyID SubjectID     X     Y     Z
      <int>     <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1        1         1     1     1     1
 2        1         2     2     2     1
 3        1         4     1     2     1
 4        2         1     1     1     0
 5        2         2     2     2     0
 6        3         1     2     1     1
 7        3         2     1     1     1
 8        3         4     2     2     1
 9        3         5     1     2     1
10        4         1     2     2     0
11        4         2     2     2     0
12        4         4     2     2     0
13        4         5     2     2     0
```